# Как вывести результат модуля в окне (собранном в Qt Designer) и передать на сохранение другому диалоговому окну?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, csv, qt-designer

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать результат работы программы, например, `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
dF = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['row_min', 'row_max', 'detector_min', 'detector_max'])
```

в окно PyQt5, а далее перейти в другое диалоговое окно для сохранения в файл `.csv`? Как связать эти 2 окна(2 модуля) через событие '*Сохранить*'? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Код окна, созданного в `Qt Designer` для отображения результата:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, widget):
        widget.setObjectName("widget")
        widget.setEnabled(True)
        widget.resize(250, 200)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        widget.setFont(font)
        widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 211, 121))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(widget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("widget", "Результат"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("widget", "DataFrame"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("widget", "Отмена"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("widget", "Сохранить"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import pandas as pd
    a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
    dF = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['row_min', 'row_max', 'detector_min', 'detector_max'])

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_widget()
    window.retranslateUi.label.setText(dF)  # Здесь возникает ошибка
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код диалогового окна для сохранения файла:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QFileDialog


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    def saveFileNameDialog(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Сохранить как ', '/path/to/default/FileName', '*.csv') 
        if fileName:
            return fileName


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = App().saveFileNameDialog()
```

Возможно, для отображения результата лучше подойдет другой тип окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что вам пока не нужно создавать никакие дополнительные окна. Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, widget):
        widget.setObjectName("widget")
        widget.setEnabled(True)
        widget.resize(250, 200)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        widget.setFont(font)
        widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(widget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 211, 121))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(widget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("widget", "Результат"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("widget", "DataFrame"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("widget", "Отмена"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("widget", "Сохранить"))
          

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.saveFileNameDialog)

        a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
        self.dF = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['row_min', 'row_max', 'detector_min', 'detector_max'])
        #print(type(self.dF), self.dF)
        
        self.label.setText(str(self.dF))
        self.label.adjustSize()
        
    def saveFileNameDialog(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, 
            'Сохранить как CSV', 
            '.',                                              #'/path/to/default/FileName', 
            'CSV(*.csv)'
        ) 
        #print(fileName)
        if fileName:
            self.dF.to_csv(fileName)        
            
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                      self, 
                      'Title', 
                      f'Content: информация сохранена в файл {fileName}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pandas as pd
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main() #Ui_widget()
    window.resize(400, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> ...ошибка на стадии создании экземпляра класса Main() (window = Main()
> NameError: name '**Main**' **is not defined**).

определите класс `Main`

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_widget):
    ...
```

> Каким методом можно вывести dF в отформатированном виде,
> например, в таблице?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] 
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]  

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]
    
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section это index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section]) 


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget= QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.data = pd.DataFrame(
          [
            [1, 2, 3, 4], 
            [5, 6, 7, 8], 
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
          ], 
          columns = ['row_min', 'row_max', 'detector_min', 'detector_max'], 
          index = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3']
        )

        self.model = TableModel(self.data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Сохранить как CSV.")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.saveFileNameDialog)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)

    def saveFileNameDialog(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, 
            'Сохранить как CSV', 
            '.',                                              #'/path/to/default/FileName', 
            'CSV(*.csv)'
        ) 
        if fileName:
            self.data.to_csv(fileName)        
            
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                      self, 
                      'Title', 
                      f'Content: информация сохранена в файл {fileName}')
                      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(500, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично. Правда, когда я импортирую этот модуль в другой файл, переношу в тот файл код, что написан после ``` if __name__ == '__main__': ``` , то возникает ошибка на стадии создании экземпляра класса Main() (window = Main() NameError: name 'Main' is not defined). Я не знаю, как исправить. Каким методом можно вывести dF в отформатированном виде, например, в таблице?

Comment: @СергейЕршов  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour .
Если у вас возникают другие вопросы, задайте `Новый Вопрос` !